# Get response from Json Post request

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I am sending POST request with two parametars id and string.

```
public void sendParams(String id,String stringSave, final VolleyCallback vc) {

    final String URL = "http://maps.b1.finki.ukim.mk/MapController/save";
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("cId", id);
    params.put("positions", stringSave);

    RequestQueue rq=Volley.newRequestQueue(GridTilesActivity.this);
    JsonRequest jr=new JsonRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL,params,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    vc.onSuccess(response);

                    Log.d("Response ",response.toString());
                    System.out.println(response);
                    String string=response.optString("positions");
                    Log.d("Positions",string);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

        }
    });

    rq.add(jr);
}
```

Now on button click i want to take response from this POST.

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                sendParams(mapId,pom,new VolleyCallback() {
                    @Override`enter code here`
                    public void onSuccess(JSONObject result) {
                        Log.d("Result","" + result.toString());
                    }
                });
```

But i dont get nothing.What's wrong with this code..?

I added Log.d("Error",volleyError.toString()) on ErrorResponse and get this:

04-19 23:52:00.375  12825-12825/com.example.bukic.mapyourroom D/Error﹕ com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Comment: Your not logging the error response, maybe that's the response your getting?

Comment: hm i add Log on error response and get this:



04-19 23:52:00.375  12825-12825/com.example.bukic.mapyourroom D/Error﹕ com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Answer (score 0):

First of, why don't you try the Volley Request on that buttonclick. Then you could handle the onResponse. Hope that helps?